# Event 'connection' fired multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

I am using Node.js for my backend. Here is my code:

```
  const http = require('http'); 
  const port = process.env.port || 1337; 

  const server = http.createServer().listen(port);  

  server.on('request',function(request, response) {
        response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' }); 
        response.end('Hello World'); 
  }); 

  server.on('connection', function() {
    console.log('connected to server!')
  });
```

I like to know why is event "connection" fired multiple time. I have not found answer on this questions in official documentation.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: And why do you use the `connection` event? It's an event that triggers when a new TCP stream is established, and lets you work with the socket, generally you wouldn't use it for a regular old webserver.

Comment: I'm assuming you connected with your browser, in your `server.on('request'` try adding `console.log(request.url)` if you visit with your browser, you'll see it visits both `/` and `/favicon.ico`

Comment: I have added console.log(request.url), I saw two request: / and /favicon.ico, but I can not understand why did I see phrase: "connected to server!" 4 times?

Comment: Hi @Alexander I am facing this issue and cannot find a solution on the internet. It will be a great help if you could tell me how you solved this problem.